Universality and continuous variation of critical exponent close to a tricritical point
A tricritical point is a point at which a second order transition line and a first order transition line merge.
At equilibrium, this point can be described by a landau potential (see for example this pdf). At the tricritical point, the transition is still continuous and thus, critical exponent, power law, ... are expected.
The mean field critical exponents of the tricritical point are different from the mean field critical exponent of the critical line. For example, the critical exponent related to the order parameter as the "temperature" is varied is $1/2$ for a critical mean field theory and $1/4$ for a tricritical point.
My question is: What happens close to the tricritical point in the critical region? I would expect the critical exponent of the system to continuously vary from $1/4$ to $1/2$ as we go deeper into the critical zone and farer from the tricritical. But Landau theory seems to only predict $1/2$ or $1/4$. So, is there some kind of critical exponent interpolation between the critical point and the tricritical point?

There is no particular reason why the exponents should gradually change. For example, for a a first transition line which terminates by a second transition point, the exponents to suddenly jump (e.g. liquid-gas, Ising ...)

@LPZ I expect that you observe some criticality in a discontinuous transition if you are close to a critical point. Probably cut-offed at some lenght still. But I agree that it is not really a continuous variation of something here, just two regimes coexisting with some typical lengt scale for both. Concerning the critical to tricritical, it seems that there is indeed a smooth crossover between the two "asymptotics": https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.9.294 I still have to understand why Landau theory does not give any information  to us about this crossover
